# Best way to convert my Swift app to Phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

So I have a native `Swift` application that basically just loads my website's URL as a `WKWebView`. It does a few other fancy things such as registering for push notifications, storing login credentials in keychain, nice loading splash screen and a few other native features.

I would like to move my entire application to Phonegap due to a [major problem](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24539) with `WKWebView` leaking memory on text input selection.

The reason I went down the native Swift path is because all I needed to do was push my code to my server, having both my iOS application and website update simultaneously, without pushing a new version to the app store.

- What would be the best approach to moving my current `Swift`
  application over to Phonegap?
- Do I simply have to scrap my entire application and restart it in
  Phonegap?
- Will Phonegap also have this same memory leak bug as the native `Swift` `WKWebView`?

Comment: if i give you free advice...if your app contain only webview and load website as a app, apple will not approve the app

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya - I have read cases that Apple rejects plain webview applications. Although, if they utilise native APIs such as keychain, push notifications, etc, they have a far better chance of being approved.

Comment: okey, so you can use cordova/phonegap or ionic framework, it has already developed plugin for push notification and keychain also

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have some advices for your questions.

- I Think your best approach would be Ionic http://ionicframework.com/ is a cordova based framework (You could use all cordova plugins) and uses MVC via angular JS, I don't know your project structure but maybe yo could find it as a great shot.
- About the WKWebView Hybrid applications works on an embed explorer in the device so you could not have any problem.

Good Luck.

Comment: Hey Leonardo. I probably should have have mentioned that my application is already mobile optimised and uses AngularJS, and Angular Material as the UI framework. It works perfectly on iOS at the moment being a native Swift application, although it's just that memory leak issue that is stopping me from pushing it to the app store at the moment.

Comment: Also, should I be looking into Cordova or Phonegap? What's the primary difference?

Comment: There's no difference Ionic Include and can use all Cordova plugins and more tools to make your project more easily to develop.